# Installing applications Silent via batch file

Tags: batch-file

My office has purchased 50 computers including Windows 8.1. I want to install supporting applications like office application, browser, 7-zip, pdf reader and others with silent installation. cause, installing applications into the computer as much as it, would take much time.

**My script is :**

```
7-zip.exe /S /norestart
```

If I run the script above, `7-zip.exe` successfully installed but not for adobe_reader.exe

How to use the silent installation correctly?

Comment: Yes, you could!!! - - - - - - - - - - Is this answer useful? I guess not. But your question isn't either. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask again.

Comment: Thank for your sugestion and forgive me

Comment: the easiest way is installing into a computer and distributing that installed image to other computers at the same time, or install Windows to multiple computers at the same time via [Windows Deployment Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772106%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) http://serverfault.com/q/347328/343888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to automate the installation of something like 7-zip.. go to your command prompt and run a command like the following:

**Code:**

```
\\Apps\dsp\7z458.exe /S
```

For more information, visit the following link... it'll hopefully give you an idea of how to automate application deployment using batch files.

**Website:**

http://windowsitpro.com/windows/use-batch-files-automate-application-installation

**Note:**

In future, please elaborate on your questions. It's rather annoying when someone posts a question with no substance.

Hope this helps,

Sohail

Comment: Thank for your sugestion and forgive me